# create graph in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, graph

I have a database like the attached image.[image]

By that table I need to draw a graph like this[image]

How to do that? I have tried with the following code:

```
function get_number($hour){
$sql = "SELECT count(POPUP)+count(`DETAIL`)+count(`DETAIL`)+count(`CALL`)+count(`MESSAGE`)+count(`ROUTE`)+count(`SHARE`)+count(`MAP`)+count(`INFO`)+ count(`WEBSITE`) as cp
FROM campaign_logs WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM logDate)=".$hour;    
    $res = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
    return $res['cp'];
}

$sql = "SELECT count(POPUP)+count(`DETAIL`)+count(`DETAIL`)+count(`CALL`)+count(`MESSAGE`)+count(`ROUTE`)+count(`SHARE`)+count(`MAP`)+count(`INFO`)+ count(`WEBSITE`) as cp,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM logDate) as h
FROM campaign_logs GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM logDate)";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$values=array(
"1" => get_number(1),
"2" => get_number(2),
"3" => get_number(3),
"4" => get_number(4),
"5" => get_number(5),
"6" => get_number(6),
"7" => get_number(7),
"8" => get_number(8),
"9" => get_number(9),
"10" => get_number(10),
"11" => get_number(11),
"12" => get_number(12),
"13" => get_number(13),
"14" => get_number(14),
"15" => get_number(15),
"16" => get_number(16),
"17" => get_number(17),
"18" => get_number(18),
"19" => get_number(19),
"20" => get_number(20),
"21" => get_number(21),
"22" => get_number(22),
"23" => get_number(23),
"24" => get_number(24)
);


$img_width=600;
$img_height=400; 
$margins=20;
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);
$bar_width=20;
$total_bars=count($values);
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1); 
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
$background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);
$border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);
$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220); 
imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);
imagefilledrectangle($img,$margins,$margins,$img_width-1-$margins,$img_height-1-$margins,$background_color); 
$max_value=max($values);
$ratio= $graph_height/$max_value; 
$horizontal_lines=20;
$horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;
for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){
$y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);
$v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);
imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);
}
for($i=0;$i< $total_bars; $i++){
list($key,$value)=each($values);
$x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
$x2= $x1 + $bar_width;
$y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;
$y2=$img_height-$margins;
imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);
imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);
imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);
} 

header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
```

But it is something different. It is calculating not separately.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Jquery plugin called Highcharts. You can use this. Please refer the below link

http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well i will reccomend you Am Charts. The best!

[Am Charts](http://www.amcharts.com/)

You can use json_encode to convert your query result so that javascript can read it.