# How to make a standard bar graph with php

Tags: php

This one does not work:

```
    <?php

$values=array(

"Jan" => 110,

"Feb" => 130,

"Mar" => 215,

"Apr" => 81,

"May" => 310,

"Jun" => 110,

"Jul" => 190,

"Aug" => 175,

"Sep" => 390,

"Oct" => 286,

"Nov" => 150,

"Dec" => 196

);

$img_width=600;

$img_height=400;

$margins=20;

$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;

$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2;

$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);

$bar_width=20;

$total_bars=count($values);

$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);

$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);

$background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);

$border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);

$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220);

imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);

$max_value=max($values);

$ratio= $graph_height/$max_value;

$horizontal_lines=20;

$horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;

for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){

$y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;

imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);

$v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);

imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);

for($i=0;$i< $total_bars; $i++){

list($key,$value)=each($values);

$x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;

$x2= $x1 + $bar_width;

$y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;

$y2=$img_height-$margins;

imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);

imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);

imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);

}


?>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to do in d3 which is stable and easy to do

Comment: possible duplicate of [create graph in php and mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337335/create-graph-in-php-and-mysql)

Comment: You can refer this http://www.highcharts.com/ or http://phpchart.net/

Comment: visit this site :[STANDARD BAR](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/example_src/example19.1.html)...this may helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Check this, once you have the svg using this lib, you can use this svg as image blob. If you still need to stick with jpeg format, you can convert it with imagemagick:

```
exec('convert test.svg test.jpeg');
```

https://github.com/sombra2eternity/inc.graph.php